# MySQL query: select all ID's and corresponding max value from other table

Tags: mysql, join

What I want: selecting all ID's from table1 and a max value from table2. If table2 doesn't contain an id, 0 is its max value.
Query I got so far:

`SELECT t1.Id, max(t2.value) FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 USING(Id) GROUP BY t2.Id;`

But the problem with this query is that it only returns an id if it is in both tables. How can I select all id's from table1 and a 0 or a max value from table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case to use a LEFT join:

```
SELECT t1.Id, coalesce(max(t2.value), 0) 
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
USING(Id) 
GROUP BY t1.Id;
```

I also changed the GROUP BY clause to use `t1.id` instead of `t2.id`.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you forgot the 'left' of left join.